# jQuery UI Slider range is not shown

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

I am using a jQuery UI Slider.It works fine but the `range div`(the part that says how much part is dragged) is not shown.
here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WmuPN/2/).
Can somebody please resolve the problem.

And another thing is, can we show indexes on the sliders.
Let's say slider has `min=0 and max=10`. Now I want to show `1` to `10` numbers as indexes to the above or down of the sliders. That will the customer that where he is in...

is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For showing the range selected,

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WmuPN/5/

**Code:**

```
<div  class="vUiSlider"></div>
<div id="slideValue"></div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
   $('.vUiSlider').slider({
     min:0,
     max:100,
     value:3,
     animate: true,
       slide: function( event, ui ) {
           $( "#slideValue" ).text(ui.value);
       }
   });
```

For more check jQuery UI documentation, http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range

**UPDATE:**

Check this one, http://jsfiddle.net/WmuPN/10/ for showing selected range color

Comment: Sorry.. I think I was poor at explaining my problem.. I don't want to show the range value. I could have done that part already...But what I was asking that I want to color the range part which has class '.ui-slider-range'. If you check the jQuery Slider demo and in #colorpicker category, they colored red upto the part that has been dragged.I hope that I am clear.